# Powershell SaveFileDialog - Pops twice

Tags: .net, winforms, powershell, savefiledialog

Please tell me why in this code the SaveFileDialog() is prompting twice for a filename.

```
Function output-scrub{
  [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.windows.forms") | Out-Null

  $global:SaveFileDialogNB = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.SaveFileDialog
  $global:SaveFileDialogNB.initialDirectory = "\\server\folder"
  $global:SaveFileDialogNB.filter = "All files (*.*)| *.*"
  $global:SaveFileDialogNB.SupportMultiDottedExtensions = $true
  #$global:SaveFileDialogNB.ShowDialog() | Out-Null
  #just to display the filename value
  $global:SaveFileDialogNB.filename
  #get just filename and the extension into a variable
  #$F1Filename = Split-Path $global:OpenFileDialog.filename -Leaf  ---commented out, only here if we only want to show filename extension alone.
    $global:SaveFileDialogNB.ShowDialog() | Out-Null
    if($SaveFileDialogNB.ShowDialog() -eq 'OK'){
        convertToHashTWO
    }
  return
}


function outPutScrubbedBalances{
    output-scrub
    write-host "file has been saved"
    return
}
```

It's driving me crazy.

Comment: You have called `$SaveFileDialogNB.ShowDialog()` twice.

Comment: I call it with `$global:SaveFileDialogNB.ShowDialog() | Out-Null` where is it being invokes a 2nd time?

Comment: I commented it out and now it only prompts once, I just want to understand which piece is producing the prompt now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have called `$ShowDialog()` twice. Once before `if` statement and the second time in the criteria part of the if statement to compare with 'OK'.

Call it once, capture the dialog result and then check the result:

```
$result = $yourDialog.ShowDialog()  
if($result  -eq "OK")               
{              
    # Do something
}
```

Or, just call it in the criteria part of the `if` statement and check the result:

```
if($yourDialog.ShowDialog() -eq "OK")
{
    # do something
}
```

---

**Side-note:** Disposing disposable components is important, don't ignore it. A better way to show the dialog and make sure it is disposed after using is:

```
$dialog = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.SaveFileDialog
try
{
    #Set up dialog, for example
    $dialog.filter = "All files (*.*)| *.*"
    if($dialog.ShowDialog() -eq "OK")
    {
        # do something here, for example
        Write-Host "Save Clicked."
    }
}
finally
{
    if($dialog) { $dialog.Dispose() }
}
```

Comment: Please post both lines where it's calls. I'm aware of the first one. `$global:SaveFileDialogNB.ShowDialog() | Out-Null` Once you point out the 2nd one I will accept this as answer. Thanks!

Comment: Here: `if($SaveFileDialogNB.ShowDialog() -eq 'OK')` you are calling `ShowDialog()` again. `ShowDIalog()` is function and the mention line, executes it  and then compare the result with 'OK'.